# Boostrap v4.6 hide nav-pills until certain time of day, then hide again JS

Tags: javascript, php, date, bootstrap-4, nav-pills

I have two nav-pills that I need to hide until a certain time of the day and then hide again at a later time of the same day. However there is a third nav-pill which shouldn´t be affected by this and visible at all times.

```
function showNavPill() {

let now = new Date();
let hours = now.getHours();
let minutes = now.getMinutes();

if (date > 15.30 && date < 17.15) {
nav-pill.show = true;
} else {
nav-pill.show = false;
}
}

showNavPill();
```

I´m quite new to this so not sure if this makes any sense?

Comment: Please refer to the JavaScript tutorial: https://www.javascripttutorial.net/javascript-dom/ for the basics

Comment: MonWas there's not enough context to your question here to give you an answer. The question has a ton of answers and there are lots of solutions you can find with a search. YOu can solve it by adding/removing classes to the specific buttons, you could target the specific element and change the styles. Are you using a framework to render your page or just basic html and js?  So try and be specific with the question and provide as much details as you can to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you compare a undefined variable `date` with two float values `15.30` and `17.15`. So let us define `date` and we will have a chance to get it working.

I simply added `const date = hours + (minutes / 100);` to convert `hours` and `minutes` into a float value that may match your conditions.

```
function showNavPill() {

    let now = new Date();
    let hours = now.getHours();
    let minutes = now.getMinutes();

    const date = hours + (minutes / 100);

    if (date > 15.30 && date < 17.15) {
        nav-pill.show = true;
    } else {
        nav-pill.show = false;
    }
}

showNavPill();
```

As a result `nav-pill.show` will be `true` between `15:31:00` and `17:14:59` (local time!) of your visitor.

But please make yourself aware that `nav-pill` is not a valid name for a variable in javascript!